# Inverse Laplace Transform using partial fractions

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

As a result of a Laplace transform, I found this result
$$\frac{1}{s^2} \cdot \frac{2}{s^2 +4}$$
Now I used partial fractions:
$2 = A(s^2+4) + B(s^2)$, giving: $(A+B)s^2 = 0$ and $4A=2$, Hence $A=\frac{1}{2}$, $B=-\frac{1}{2}$
So the fraction can be written as:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{s^2} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{s^2+4}$$

But how to continue now? How do I get back to a function with "t"?
Of course the first part is: $\frac{1}{2}t$, but I cannot see the second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that

$$ \mathcal{L}\left\{\sin(bt)\right\}=\frac{b}{s^2+b^2} $$

therefore

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{s^2+b^2}\right\}=\frac{1}{b}\sin(bt) $$

Comment: Of course! Thanks John for awaken me!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Now you take the inverse of each term. Remember that

$$
\mathcal{L}\{t \mu(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2}
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{L}\{\sin(\omega t)\mu(t)\} = \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}
$$

where $\mu(t)$ is the unit step. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms) a list of functions and their transform

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{2}{s^2+4}\right\}=\sin(2t)$$

Now divide both sides by $2$ and you have your result.